# iOS 7 -- Extended Status Bar Overlays Navigation Bar after hide then show

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I have a fairly simple app that uses a navigation controller.  The problem is that the extended status bar (in-call/ hot spot) overlays the navigation bar after hiding the status bar and reshowing it.

The navigation bar and extended status bar are laid out correctly when the app launches, or reopening the app.

I'm using the standard way to hide and show the status bar.

I haven't seen any similar question or problems on SO or google.

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: you got any solution ?

Comment: It seems to stem from the IIViewDeckController library, no solution yet, was pushed to the back burner, have u had similar issues?